# How to update FBRequest.requestForMe() on facebooksdk v4.0.1?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, facebook-sdk-4.0

So, I made application on iphone. I'm using login with facebook and currently upgrade my facebooksdk to lastest version. Some of my code happen to have an error. Below is mycode:

```
let request = FBRequest.requestForMe()
    request.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            if let userData = result as? NSDictionary {

                let facebookId = userData["id"] as! String
                self.user.name = userData["name"]as! String
                //                        self._fbuser.location = userData["location"]["name"] as String
                self.user.gender = userData["gender"] as! String
                self.user.imgUrl = NSURL(string: NSString(format: "https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?type=large&return_ssl_resources=1", facebookId) as String)
                self.user.isFacebookUser = true
            }

        } else {

            if let userInfo = error.userInfo {

                if let type: AnyObject = userInfo["error"] {

                    if let msg = type["type"] as? String {
                        if msg == "OAuthException" { // Since the request failed, we can check if it was due to an invalid session
                            println("The facebook session was invalidated")
                            self.onLogout("")
                            return
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            println("Some other error: \(error)")
        }
    })
```

So how can I fix it ? what code that equal or similiar to **FBRequest.requestme** ?

Comment: @AshishKakkad yes, I already done the login. I just need the user data

Comment: @AshishKakkad how can I do that ?

Comment: did you seen the answer? It's working for you?

Comment: ya , your answer work for me

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Get user info in facebook sdk 4.x swift

```
@IBAction func btnFBLoginPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    var fbLoginManager : FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
    fbLoginManager .logInWithReadPermissions(["email"], handler: { (result, error) -> Void in
        if (error == nil){
            var fbloginresult : FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult = result
            if(fbloginresult.grantedPermissions.containsObject("email"))
            {
                self.getFBUserData()
                fbLoginManager.logOut()
            }
        }
    })
}

func getFBUserData(){
    if((FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()) != nil){
        FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email"]).startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in
            if (error == nil){
                println(result)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Output :

```
{
    email = "ashishkakkad8@gmail.com";
    "first_name" = Ashish;
    id = 910855688971343;
    "last_name" = Kakkad;
    name = "Ashish Kakkad";
    picture =     {
        data =         {
            "is_silhouette" = 0;
            url = "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xpf1/v/t1.0-1/p200x200/10394859_900936369963275_5557870055628103117_n.jpg?oh=fefbfca1272966fc78286c36741f9ac6&oe=55C89225&__gda__=1438608579_9133f15e55b594f6ac2306d61fa6b6b3";
        };
    };
}
```