# Facebook SDK 4.2 FBGraphUser protocol update

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am working on an Xcode project that has Facebook SDK 3.1.4. I am currently updating the SDK to 4.2.
I was just wondering if someone can help me with the update related to FBGraphUser protocol and how I can update that for Facebook SDK 4.2. 
I have looked around and found that they have defined it in FBSDKShareKit. I looked at FBSDKShareOpenGraphObject as well but was not able to figure out how to update it. Or should I be using FBSDKProfile?
Should I be using FBSDKShareOpenGraphValueContaining protocol?

For example,
I have a method like so:

```
-exampleMethod: (NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *) user
```

I was wondering how I should update this for SDK v4.2?

I have searched on Google, StackOverflow, and Reddit but have been unsuccessful.
If someone could help me, that would be amazing!

Thanks for your help in advance and apologies for the ill-structured question.

Comment: what exactly you want ? a simple implementation of Facebook sdk 4.1 is here https://github.com/varun-naharia/Facebook-Intigration

Comment: Thank you for that link. I just wanted to know how to implement FBGraphUser in the new SDK.
I was going through the SDK again and noticed that they say, "FBGraphObject and related protocols are removed such as FBGraphUser. Open Graph types are defined more completely in FBSDKShareKit.framework and used there for sharing. Otherwise you can simply work with NSDictionary instances to represent Facebook Graph entities."
So does that mean that I can simply get rid of the protocol from my method parameter and still be able to work?

Comment: just for people will come here in the future - you can find a great solution here -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30187418/how-to-update-fbrequest-requestforme-on-facebooksdk-v4-0-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to facebook upgrade [guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/upgrading-4.x)

> Graph API Update
>
> Requests - FBSDKGraphRequest and FBSDKGraphRequestConnection are in
>   FBSDKCoreKit and provide helpers to access the Graph API. They are
>   very similar to FBRequest and FBRequestConnection in v3.x. By default
>   they use [FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] for issuing requests so
>   you typically issue requests after login. For example:
>
> ```
> FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me"
>                                                                  parameters:nil];
>   [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection,
> ```
>
> id result, NSError *error) {
>           // TODO: handle results or error of request.
>         }];
>
> Batch Requests - As in v3.x, you construct a
>   FBSDKGraphRequestConnection to add multiple requests to send in a
>   batch.
>
> FBViewController and related picker classes such as FBCacheDescriptor
>   have been removed. If you want to display Graph API results in a table
>   view, you can do it manually. Take a look at the Scrumptious or
>   RPSSample for ideas to get started.

**Take a look at the Scrumptious or RPSSample for ideas to get started**

Comment: Thank you. I was just wondering one more thing, I have a [FBSession openOpenActiveSessionWithAllowLoginUI:YES]; How should I go about updating it? Should I work with FBSDKLoginManager or FBSDKAccessToken. The file is of type NSObject.

Comment: it depends on you but I think FBSDKAccessToken should be better option